# Bypass robots.txt in cross domain queries

Tags: jquery, robots.txt

I'm using [AnyOrigin](http://anyorigin.com) for cross domain queries, and I've discovered that the site [nytimes.com](http://nytimes.com) has a robots.txt in place.

See [this Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4VKr/). Try putting `http://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/05/world/middleeast/in-aipac-speech-obama-warns-against-loose-talk-of-war.html` in the box and it will return `Log In - The New York Times`, which is not the title of the page.

Any ideas about this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This probably have little to do with the robots.txt file, as that doesn't really block anything and is more optional, either they are blocking you because you are not sending a proper header along, and they see that it is not a browser that is trying to access the site, or they actually do require a login to view that article.

Did some checking, the problem is that cookies must be enabled, and since you are not using a browser it redirects to the login page for NY Times.

Try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/L4VKr/1/) to see the result you are getting.

Comment: Everyone can view that article - just go [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/05/world/middleeast/in-aipac-speech-obama-warns-against-loose-talk-of-war.html). but anyway, is there a way to send a proper header? without using a server-side proxy of course, as I can't use that.

Comment: Don't know of any service that will do that, i would think using cURL in PHP would be the easiest, no need for a proxy, but you will need to use your web server to do the request.

Comment: Wow, ok that's a problem. So I don't expect there to be a way to fake enabled cookies, is there. Oh well.

Comment: I'm kind of limited to Javascript and JQuery.

Comment: Not unless anyOrigin has some sort of option that will let you enable cookies in the querystring you send them. JS is'nt really suited for this kind of thing, and it will only except JSON, but anyOrigin does the request for you based on the querystring and returns the site as JSON, so cookies will have to be enabled on their end, or you will have to use another service or your server, only options I can think of. There are some tutorials around on how to use yahoo, but don't think that will help much when it comes to cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [result](http://anyorigin.com/get/?url=http://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/05/world/middleeast/in-aipac-speech-obama-warns-against-loose-talk-of-war.html) that AnyOrigin gets you'll notice that it really is getting a "please log in" page, whereas if you go directly to the NYTimes page, you get the real page. This isn't going to be related to robots.txt because robots.txt is more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules. I'd wager it's either the User-Agent being sent by AnyOrigin or the NYTimes not allowing AnyOrigin itself.

Comment: Oh I see now. It has `&REFUSE_COOKIE_ERROR=SHOW_ERROR` tagged on to the end of the url when looking at the AnyOrigin JSON.